# Use CMS for Relational Data management?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, relational-database, data-management

Should one use a CMS (Such as Joomla or Wordpress for example) to enable displaying, categorization, searches and manipulation of data etc.?

I have ha need to create a solution for taking an excel sheet online with basic relations between data for example Country -> Project -> Info, Project -> Project participants.

Very basic, maintenance by non develop people necessary hence my investigation of a CMS.

I have tried to investigate and compare different CMS but most exemplify by showing static content pages like small business, bloggs or wiki site. I use to develop Java MVC and SQL databases but I believe custom made is over kill and not the right way to go in this case.

I would very much appreciate examples of sites using CMS this way, suggested CMSs or other suggested solutions.

Comment: One of the main benefits of relational databases is not just the storage of data but the maintaining of the relationships between that data, which I don't believe CMS systems generally do.  The closest database analogy may be a document database, where a CMS basically stores a schema-less set of content which you'd define.  But even that analogy is a bit of a stretch, because any database is going to have more structure than a system that pretty much just holds a string of formatted displayable content.  In short, I wouldn't think that a CMS is the tool for this part of the job.

Comment: ok, I was hoping that I could somehow categorize my CMS articles/data/info. I would then have a country category and then under the country category have a project category and a user can then add a new project or country. Under that project add info & project particiapants. The relationship in the CMS would be very linear but I would be able to define relationships so that when searching for example a project participant I would see that he/she is working in projects in multiple countries. It feels like it should be possible to at least have hierarchical categorization!?

Comment: Hierarchical categories should definitely be possible.  You're mainly just going to be missing any referential integrity between the data entities.  You also may run into a lot of data being "stringly typed" instead of strongly typed as well.  If that's ok, then no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Yii Framework since you could build the database structure by Gii and for maintenance there is a lot of Gadgets inside Yii community to make non developers make the maintenance on the Yii Applications
http://www.yiiframework.com/